# iOS "Data Protection" depends on user passcode set or not?

Tags: ios, encryption, data-protection

When developing iOS Apps one can chose to add the Capability "Data Protection", which then offers more "protection".

What, after a lot of searching and reading, is still unclear to me: will the files declared to be secured with "complete protection" be encrypted even if the user doesn't set a passcode?
Every thing I found always somehow involves the passcode of the user. I need to have things encrypted even though the user has no passcode set.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the iOS documentation ([Protecting Data Using On-Disk Encryption](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW21)):

> Data protection is available on most iOS devices and is subject to the following requirements:
>
> - The file system on the user’s device must support data protection. Most devices support this behavior.
> - The user must have an active passcode lock set for the device.

I'd say the 2nd bullet point answers your question.

Comment: Thx. This page I haven't found. Apple has a lot of documentation but sometimes lack proper linking and/or SEO. :/